# How to adjust SQL aggregation by date query result to merge values in same level where nulls exist for some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

Sorry for the messy title but here is my problem description.

```
| id|dateKey|colA|colB|colD|colE|
+---+-------+----+----+----+----+
| 1 |180111 | 1  | 5  |Null|Null|
| 2 |180111 |Null|Null| 6  | 7  |
| 3 |180111 | 2  | 5  | 3  | 2  |
```

I have the above table data but I want the result to appear as below when data aggregated (e.g. sum) by date:

```
|dateKey|colA|colB|colD|colE|
+-------+----+----+----+----+
|180111 | 3  | 10 |9   |9   |
```

Is there a way to do it as I am struggling to achieve it?

Note: this query will be running on 10 Gb of data with date filters.

Comment: Do you have a sample query? You can use coalesce to convert null or empty record to zero

Comment: You can find the answer and live demo her- https://rextester.com/MKYY62432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` query with `SUM` should already meet your needs:

```
SELECT
    dateKey,
    SUM(colA) AS colA,
    SUM(colB) AS colB,
    SUM(colD) AS colD,
    SUM(colE) AS colE
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY dateKey;
```

The reason this should work is that `SUM` by default ignores `NULL` values, so only the numbers present should end up in the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ISNULL` to ignore and convert `null` values to zero as shown below.

```
create table #temp (id int, dateKey int, colA int, colB int, colD int, colE int)
insert into #temp values (1,180111, 1 , 5 ,Null,Null),
( 2,180111, Null  , Null  , 6 , 7 ),
( 3,180111, 2 , 5 , 3 , 2  )

SELECT
    dateKey,
    SUM(ISNULL(colA,0)) AS colA,
    SUM(ISNULL(colB,0)) AS colB,
    SUM(ISNULL(colD,0)) AS colD,
    SUM(ISNULL(colE,0)) AS colE
FROM #temp
GROUP BY dateKey;
```